# How to format pumped file in Oracle SQL Developer in any way?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, dynamic-sql, flat-file, datapump

My problem is that I unloaded a table from Oracle db into a text file with the following code:

```
PACKAGE BODY:
procedure d_datapump (tab_name in varchar2,
                      def_dir  in varchar2 default 'MY_DIR',
                      xt_location in varchar2)          
                      is


  d_query varchar2(10000);                                        
  d_result varchar2(10000);
  begin       
    d_query :=  ' create table ' || tab_name || '_xt
                                             organization external
                                             (
                                               type oracle_datapump
                                               default directory ' || def_dir || ' 
                                               location ( ' || chr(39) || xt_location || chr(39) || ' )
                                             )
                                             as
                                             select * from ' || tab_name;


    d_result := '';
    dbms_output.put_line (d_query);
    execute immediate  d_query;  
    dbms_output.put_line (d_result); 
  end d_datapump;
```

thereafter the call:

```
begin
   david_ext_table.d_datapump(tab_name => 'D_TEST_TABLE',
                              xt_location => 'test_pac.txt');
end;
```

And it worked, but the result in my txt is something like this:

"?xml...many xml parameters  .../ROWSET"

"XXXXXYYYYYZZZZZ§§§§§00000< "XXXXXYYYYYZZZZZ§§§§§00000<
"XXXXXYYYYYZZZZZ§§§§§00000< "XXXXXYYYYYZZZZZ§§§§§00000<

But I would like to see something like this (without xml block):

```
 col1 |  col2 |  col3 |  col4 | col5
-------------------------------------
XXXXX | YYYYY | ZZZZZ | §§§§§ | 00000
XXXXX | YYYYY | ZZZZZ | §§§§§ | 00000
XXXXX | YYYYY | ZZZZZ | §§§§§ | 00000
```

I have spent hours browsing for a solution and the only things I could find the tons of suggestion to use spooling and UTL_FILE instead of this way, because the datapump is only for creating a binary file, but It is obviously not binary but an ordinary text file.
Is there any way to format it?

Comment: It isn't designed to be human readable; you don't want to just query it, as `select * from d_test_table_xt'? Or you could view it with a XML editor (e.g. XMLNotepad) I guess, if you remove the binary parts at the start and end of the file, to just leave the rowset node. It isn't clear what you end goal is, or why you wan to do this over spool/utl_file.

Comment: No, I don't want to select it or call it back to the Developer at all (only if I have no other choice). I want to create ordered, readable text files which contain separated columns for further process in a publisher software. The reason I chose this method is the much better performance (<0.1 sec at 1M rows). The recently used method is spooling but it's too slow. I tried the UTL_FILE, but with more than 500k rows it was even worse. I hope there is some way to use datapump with the appropriate result.

Comment: I assume the publisher software can't handle the XML itself? Did you spool with `set termout off`? Or try SQL Developer's Tools->Database Export? Though that would be a manual process, and perhaps you want to automate this. I don't believe there is any way to do what you want with the datapump driver anyway, since it's designed to create files it can read itself - which would be tricky with that kind of text formatting.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It can't. And yes, I would like to build an automatic process as fast as it can be. It's sad that there is no option for this.